# CloudFormation findInMap returns null

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I'm creating an AWS SAM template and would like to use mappings to store some commonly used paths.
My mappings definitions look like that:

```
Mappings:
  envs:
    np:
      vpcId: vpc-1412343432
    prod:
      vpcId: vpc-4123121323
  paths:
    example:
      foo1: /{stage}/foo1/
      foo2: /{stage}/foo2/
      foo3: /{stage}/foo3/
```

and later in the template, I have a function definition with `!findInMap`

```
  myFunc:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.myFunc
      Role: !GetAtt myFunc.Arn
      Events:
        foo:
          Type: HttpApi
          Properties:
            Path: !FindInMap [ paths, example, foo1 ]
            Method: get
            ApiId: !Ref fooApi
```

When I run sam deploy it returns an error `Event with id [foo] is invalid. Api Event must have a String specified for 'Path'`. It looks that findInMap returns empty value. Do you know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: As a quick check, if you hardcode `/{stage}/foo1/` in `path`, instead of using `FindInMap`, does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the problem is with `!FindInMap`. I quickly validated it using following addition to my template.

```
Outputs:
  MaverickOutput:
    Value: !FindInMap [ paths, example, foo1 ]
```

The value (`/{stage}/foo1/`) was reflected in the CloudFormation stack output post `sam deploy`.

Coming to the reason why it did not work with the Api event. If you follow this [link to official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-api.html), you can see this.

> The object describing an Api event source type. If an AWS::Serverless::Api resource is defined, the path and method values must correspond to an operation in the OpenAPI definition of the API.

This combined with the error (`Api Event must have a String specified for 'Path'."`) that you are receiving, I think it is fair to assume that this resource does not accept references which will be resolved during deployment time.

PS:
I could not find any documentation to support my theory, but another fact which supports this is that the maps can also store numbers and there won't be any way to know what the final value is going to be until actual deployment takes place. Therefore, if deployment time references were allowed, you might actually refer to a number for the `Path` value.

Comment: Indeed, I've tried to move !findInMap to the other parts of the template, and then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify path as string

```
Mappings:
  envs:
    "np":
      vpcId: "vpc-1412343432"
    "prod":
      vpcId: "vpc-4123121323"
  paths:
    "example":
      foo1: "/{stage}/foo1/"
      foo2: "/{stage}/foo2/"
      foo3: "/{stage}/foo3/"
```

Comment: I've tried with the strings but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @Pawel When I used the path there, the error changed for me. Something around referencing correct resource for ApiId but I guess that is okay since this is not complete template.